# Turning arrays into an integer (int) when we need to swap pairs of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, int

I have made a method on array , and now I'm trying to convert the array into int. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
public Number swapPairs() {
    int n = 0 ; 
    this.num =  n ; 
    int    []a; 

    for (int i=0 ; i==getNumOfDigits();i++){
        a[i]=n%10 ; 
        int k = a[i];
        a[i]=a[i-1];
        a[i-1]=k ;
        a[0]=a[0];



    }
   []a= scr.nextInt();
    Number New = new Number(j);
```

Comment: thanks guys , i totally changed it and finished my project , but since im a beginner so can any one help me to test this class ? in the next comment

Comment: public Number swapPairs(){     // this method returns the swap of all two numbers that behind of it  
  String s=""+num , n="";
  char c,t;
  for (int i = 0; i<getNumOfDigits(); i+=2){
   if(i+1<getNumOfDigits()){
    c=s.charAt(i);
    t=s.charAt(i+1);
    n+=t+""+c;
   }
  }
  if(getNumOfDigits()%2==0){ 
   int nam = Integer.parseInt(n);
   Number num = new Number ( nam);
   return num ;     
  }else {
   n=n+s.charAt(getNumOfDigits()-1);
   int nam = Integer.parseInt(n);
   Number num = new Number ( nam);
   return num ;  }

Comment: This should be made into a new question if you are asking a new question.

Comment: Please add a tag for which programming language you're using. It looks like Java?

Comment: Yeb its java , i made a tag

Answer (score 0):

In that case, if you want to convert an array into an integer, you should have at least the same variable count as the array itself. For example, the user has inputted 10 values so the array initialization would be `a[0]` to `a[9]`. Then you should have 10 variables which holds the values from the array.

e.g.:

```
temp1 = a[0];
temp2 = a[1];
temp3 = a[2];
temp4 = a[3];
temp5 = a[4];
temp6 = a[5];
temp7 = a[6];
temp8 = a[7];
temp9 = a[8];
temp10 = a[9];
```

Answer (score 0):

What is info being put into it.

You don't declare an array size, and you are not declaring datatypes.

`this.num` and `src` dont mean anything in the context of this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this method returns the swap of all two numbers that behind of it  
public Number swapPairs(){         
    String s=""+num , n="";
    char c,t;

    for (int i = 0; i<getNumOfDigits(); i+=2) {
        if(i+1<getNumOfDigits()) {
            c=s.charAt(i);
            t=s.charAt(i+1);
            n+=t+""+c;
        }
    }

    if(getNumOfDigits()%2==0) { 
        int nam = Integer.parseInt(n);
        Number num = new Number (nam);
        return num;              
    } else {
        n=n+s.charAt(getNumOfDigits()-1);
        int nam = Integer.parseInt(n);
        Number num = new Number ( nam);
        return num; 
    }
}
```